# How to define (in routes) passing multiple Long values from a view template

Tags: playframework-2.0

In my Play 2.0.4 project I have a view template that takes two values in its parameters, a list and a long.

```
@(listOfBooks: List[Book], oID: Long)
```

I know the correct values are being passed because I print them in the main body of the template inside a loop and they display as I would expect.

```
@for(book <- listOfBooks) {

    <li>
        <b>Original ID: </b>@oID<br>
        <b>New ID: </b>@book.id<br>

    </li>
```

I am trying to invoke a controller method from this view with the values oID and book.id.

I have a controller method defined to handle this and I invoke it when this button is pressed.

```
<a href routes.Application.addAssociate(oID, book.id)"> Button </a>
```

I have tried a number of things in the router file but I can't get it to work. This is the current application route defined:

```
GET     /addAssociate/:oID/:id                   controllers.Application.addAssociate(oID: Long, id: Long)
```

When the button described above is pressed the URL in my browser changes to this:

```
http://localhost:9000/routes.Application.addAssociate(oID,%20book.id)
```

And I get the error message:

> Action not found For request 'GET
>   /routes.Application.addAssociate(oID,%20book.id)'

I think the problem is how I am defining the connection in the router file I am not sure how to pass multiple Long values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a magic `@` character in your view template indicating that your URL is dynamic:

```
<a href="@routes.Application.addAssociate(oID, book.id)"> Button </a>
```

Comment: Something so trivial. Been holding me up for like an hour! Thanks.